# Unique identifier for file in Git Repository

Tags: git, file, repository, uniqueidentifier, identifier

Does there exist any unique identifier for files in a Git Repository? This unique identifier must be the same after some commits (modifying files), or after renaming and moving file(s).

Does such a thing exist?

I tried `git ls-files --debug` but I didn't find a unique identifier with the characteristics listed above.

Comment: **See also:** https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34874343/how-can-i-uniquely-identify-a-git-repository

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The only unique identifier for a file ("blob") within a git repo is its SHA-1, but that is a checksum of the file's contents (plus the fact of it being a file/blob).  It remains constant only while the file's contents remain unchanged.  It does not depend on the file's *name*, but it does depend on its *contents*, so modifying the file will change the SHA-1.

You could make up your own unique ID but you would also have to do your own tracking, mapping the ID to the current tree-relative name (or git-name, i.e., SHA-1) and changing it when the file is renamed (or modified, respectively).

Answer (score 3):

No, there isn't one. If you modify it, it's a different file from Git's point of view.